# Icon font to PNG converter

Tags: gratis, media-converter, font-utility, font

I'm looking for a tool that quickly extracts / converts all icons from a **vector-based icon font** (OpenType, TrueType, Type-1) **to** good old **PNG files** with given

- **dimensions** (e.g. 48px x 48px)
- **foreground color** (e.g. white)
- **background color** (e.g. transparent)

I don't care much about the file name pattern.

Target OS: Windows or Linux CLI

Comment: Huh, I also have need for this exact product. (though I don't care what OS).
I suspect I'll end up doing it with ImageMagic from the linux commandline

Comment: Hey, I've got this crazy idea: I remove the OS requirement and you post a short how-to about ImageMagick?

Comment: I haven't done it yet. But if I do, I will make a post saying how. (I'm not sure how, but I remember it is possible)

Comment: What do you mean by "all icons"? What kind of icons where? It doesn't seem that you're talking about Windows desktop icons ...

Comment: @hippietrail: I'm asking about icons contained in a font file.

Comment: @JensPiegsa: So I think you mean ***["glyphs"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph)*** in that case. ***[Icons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_icon)*** are something different... AHA! I now realize you are talking about what are usually called ***bitmap fonts*** or ***raster fonts***.

Comment: I referred to the broader meaning of icon: symbol -- in my case I have vector-based not bitmap-based glyphs.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as discussed in comments, [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) will do your task quickly and a efficiently. To do what you want in windows you could use this (windows) batch file: (Just change the background colour (`bg`) - can be almost any color identifier - font path (`f`), font size (`ps`), extension/format (`ext`), size(`s`)). See [the ImageMagick docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) for more options you could do/details on valid values.

```
@ECHO OFF
set f=C:/Windows/Fonts/ITCEDSCR.TTF
set ps=44
set bg=white
set ext=png
set s=48x48
set alpha=A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W Z Y Z
set num=0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
For %%X in (%alpha% %num%) do (
    convert -font %f% -pointsize %ps% -size %s% -background %bg% label:%%X %%X.%ext%)
pause
exit
```